# lettuce 6.1.8 unable to connect to redis

Tags: redis, lettuce

When upgrading to springboot2.6.9, the lettuce should be upgraded to 6.1.8, and at the same time, the software should be upgraded to redis6.2.7. When the project is started, redis cannot be connected

IllegalAccessError:classio/lettuce/core/protocol/CommandHandler illegally accessing “private”member of class io/lettuce/core/protocol/ChannelLogDescriptor
[image]

An error was reported in the production environment, but other environments could not be reproduced